# Is there a base64 file encoding command that doesn't show up on screen?

Tags: batch-file, base64, certutil

I am well aware of `certutil -encode`, however in my use case I do not want the end user to see a console window open.

Comment: This is a programming site. Why don't you try reading the spec and writing code. See RFC4648 https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use vbs to hide the console for the certutil command. create a `.vbs` extention file with something like:

```
Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "cmd /c certutil OPTIONS -encode Infile Outfile", 0, False
```

Run it as `cscript filename.vbs`

Alternatively if you have the certutil commands in a batch file, call the batch file instead.

```
Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\somedir\batchfile.cmd", 0, False
```